# ng-click Angular JS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

New to Angular JS, trying to access the click event using ng-click.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="selectNav($event)">Click</button>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', function(){ 
    $scope.selectNav = function($event){ 
       console.log($event); 
    } 
});
```

On click of the button, its not giving the value of $event. Can any one let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: have you tried putting alert($event);?

Comment: derp... he is logging it to the console...

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ds7z5/1/ - which angular version is used

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Yes tried but no action is happening.

Comment: I tried jsfiddle share by @ArunPJohny, and it seems fine to me also.

Comment: this is not the right approach to use $event in controller you should write directive and handle those dom logic over there

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed you didn't pass `$scope` to the controller.
try to fix that maybe

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', function($scope){ 
    $scope.selectNav = function($event){ 
       console.log($event); 
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

problem with `$scope` in your controller.

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){ 
    $scope.selectNav = function($event){ 
       console.log($event); 
    } 
}]);
```